# Cannot find WebViewContext for WkWebView on iOS Simulator with Appium

Tags: ios, appium, wkwebview, xcuitest

I currently have no access to the WKWebView via Appium. I start the driver with the following capabilities:

```
var options = new AppiumOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "iOS");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", "15.5");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "iPad (5th generation)");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("language", "DE");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", "/Users/testautomatisierung/Projects/TestAppWebView/TestAppWebView/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/ipad6.4-15.5/TestAppWebView.app");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("derivedDataPath", "/Users/testautomatisierung/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-ciegwgvxzxdrqthilmrmczmqvrgu");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("webviewConnectTimeout", "90000");
options.AddAdditionalCapability("safariLogAllCommunication", "true");
```

My Appium Server Logs tell me:

```
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle 'com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle 'process-SafariViewService'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle 'com.apple.SafariViewService'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle '*'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:6483' for bundle 'de.TestAppWebView'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:6483 (try #1 of 20)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Attempting app 'PID:6483'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to app 'PID:6483' (id: 42): 'connectToApp'
[debug] [ios-device] Sending message to Web Inspector:
[debug] [ios-device] {
[debug] [ios-device]   "__argument": {
[debug] [ios-device]     "WIRConnectionIdentifierKey": "470505be-7934-41cd-881e-d2e390be4ffd",
[debug] [ios-device]     "WIRApplicationIdentifierKey": "PID:6483"
[debug] [ios-device]   },
[debug] [ios-device]   "__selector": "_rpc_forwardGetListing:"
[debug] [ios-device] }
[debug] [ios-device] Received message from Web Inspector:
[debug] [ios-device] {
[debug] [ios-device]   "__argument": {
[debug] [ios-device]     "WIRApplicationIdentifierKey": "PID:6483",
[debug] [ios-device]     "WIRListingKey": {}
[debug] [ios-device]   },
[debug] [ios-device]   "__selector": "_rpc_applicationSentListing:"
[debug] [ios-device] }
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from send (id: 42): '["PID:6483",{}]'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending to Web Inspector took 2ms
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Empty page dictionary received
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Error checking application: 'Empty page dictionary received'. Retrying connection
[RemoteDebugger] Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
[debug] [XCUITest] No available web pages: Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
[debug] [XCUITest] No web frames found.
[debug] [W3C (4114d2e3)] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]
```

In Safari i enable the development modus and i can find my WebAppView on the simulator. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information but a hybrid app in its essence is a native app with webviews. Usually when you reach a webview screen you have to switch from Native context to Webview context in the code to be able to interact with it. If your app directly loads into a webview you can try providing `autoWebview` capability as `true`

Comment: I have an ios app that first starts the webview directly. When I then try to switch the context, Appium doesn't find the WebView. What additional information can I give? I've already tried the autowebview property with no success.

Comment: Is it a real device or sim? Have you enabled Web Inspector and Remote Automation for Safari from Settings? Is the application a debuggable build? Are you able to select the phone and application through Safari(developer menu) and see the webpage in the webview?

Comment: I start the tests on a simulator. For testing purposes, I set up a simple Xamarin IOS standard app that hosts the WKWebView. The WKWebView calls up a website. The Web Inspector is activated. I get the WebView read out via Safari. However, Appium does not show me the WebView context.
Appium version: 1.22.3
XCode: 13.4.1
MAC: macOS Montery v12.3
Simulator: See Appium Options